# Meaning of "Comment ne plus se mettre dans tous ses états pour un oui ou pour un non"?

Tags: sens, traduction

I came across this sentence:

Comment ne plus se mettre dans tous ses états pour un oui ou pour un non ?

(It's the first sentence of the preface of  *Petite Philosophie Du Matin*.)

This seems to translate to "How to stop being in all its states for a yes or a no?" That doesn't make sense to me. Is that a correct translation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that is not a correct translation, and the reason for that is first, that  "se mettre dans tous ses états" is  an idiomatic expression that means "*to get into a state*" (strangely enough… when in French it's a matter of *all of one's possible states* (whatever that is), in English it is just a matter of *one state* (whatever that is)…), and second, that the same goes for "pour un oui ou pour un non" (for a trifle).

> ([Cambridge Dictionnary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/french-english/se-mettre-dans-tous-ses-etats)) **se mettre dans tous ses états**
> ***get into a state*** to become very upset or anxious
> ♦ She got into a right state when her daughter did not come home from school at the usual time.

So your translation might be as follows.

- How to avoid getting into a state for no apparent/good reason. (*also, "for a trifle", "for any little reason", over nothing", "at the drop of a hat", [Word Reference](https://www.wordreference.com/fren/pour%20un%20oui%20ou%20pour%20un%20non)*))